# Prevent Controls in ControlTemplate inheriting global Styles (WPF)

Tags: wpf, styles, custom-controls, controltemplate, inheritance

I have this generic style for a custom control with this Template.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyType}">        
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyType}">                    
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <local:MyControl />
                    </Border>
                    ...
```

if this control is used in a project where is this style globaly set:

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
</Style>
```

But MyControl is an ordinary `UserControl` containing:
...

```
<Border .. />
```

Then the Border in the UserControl (residing in the Template) inherits this style as well (Padding 3 etc.)
Is there any way to say the controls in the ControlTemplate not to inhertit these global styles?
Just to mention. It is a Generic Template

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood you correctly. 
Did some work around as I had similar situation where all my control's styles specified globally and inherited automatically without x:key.

I had to remove styles for some controls and apply different style for some controls.

In that situation I have created separate style (Below e.g. wants remove styles) so just created Empty style and used where ever and to which ever control it was required.

**Empty Style:**

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="EmptyStyle"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Grid.Resources>
```

**Apply to Control:**

```
<TextBlock Text="First Name" Style="{StaticResource EmptyStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your Style in a resource dictionary with a x:Key, I've always do this and my style is applied only if I specify the key on my control.

Comment: Yes but imagine that the style should be applied for all the controls in the app. Except of this custom control..